# Group strings by matched values (strings are link paths)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some links which I am pulling from my Github API, into a view in my Rails application. The goal is to have these links eventually be grouped by folder if they are nested, and to just be unique and stand alone if they don't have any children.

Here is a sample of what I'm getting back from a Github repo:

```
app
app/assets
app/assets/images
app/assets/images/.keep
app/assets/javascripts
app/assets/javascripts/ace.js
app/assets/javascripts/application.js
app/assets/javascripts/editor.js.coffee
app/assets/stylesheets
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
app/assets/stylesheets/editor.css.scss
app/controllers
app/controllers/application_controller.rb
app/controllers/concerns
```

The `http://` part of these links is always going to be the same, and I'm just concatenating it for now in my view to make the path absolute.

How do I group them by folder? I would imagine some string method, but I'm not sure what the best method would be. Also, is Ruby or JavaScript the best solution?

Comment: You need to show an example of what you mean by "grouped". Do subdirectory entries in your list that do not contain filenames count? How about "hidden" files like ".keep"?

Comment: Both Ruby and JavaScript can do this equally well. YOU have to decide whether you want the computing done on the server or the client. If it's on the client, remember that you'll be sending the list of all files available to the client, which then exposes your entire file list to someone who could use that information in ways you don't want.

Comment: Tin man....amazing feedback and questions. Thank you! So Using the method below I was able to isolate the directories this out in Ruby. But my question now lies in how to show the directories and links to the files in folders in my views. Its fine for the user to see all the files because these are all public repos from Github...if the file was private then they would put it in the .gitignore and it wouldn't even pull up. So.... yea... can u tell me how to do it now :-) (I <3 stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way in Ruby, assuming that you've got the list in an Array called `paths`:

```
grouped = paths.group_by { |p| File.dirname(p) }
```

This will produce a hash containing:

```
{"."=>["app"],
 "app"=>["app/assets", "app/controllers"],
 "app/assets"=>
  ["app/assets/images", "app/assets/javascripts", "app/assets/stylesheets"],
 "app/assets/images"=>["app/assets/images/.keep"],
 "app/assets/javascripts"=>
  ["app/assets/javascripts/ace.js",
   "app/assets/javascripts/application.js",
   "app/assets/javascripts/editor.js.coffee"],
 "app/assets/stylesheets"=>
  ["app/assets/stylesheets/application.css",
   "app/assets/stylesheets/editor.css.scss"],
 "app/controllers"=>
  ["app/controllers/application_controller.rb", "app/controllers/concerns"]}
```

If you want to get rid of the directory elements (like `app/assets` under `app`), and you want the value arrays to contain basenames rather than full paths (`application.css` instead of `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`), you can use:

```
grouped.each do |dir, paths|
  # If the path is also a hash key in "grouped", it must be a directory
  paths.delete_if { |path| grouped.has_key? path }
  # Replace each element with its basename
  paths.map! { |path| File.basename(path) }
end
```

Finally, to omit empty directories:

```
grouped.delete_if { |dir, paths| paths.empty? }
```

All of this will leave you with:

```
{"app/assets/images"=>[".keep"],
 "app/assets/javascripts"=>["ace.js", "application.js", "editor.js.coffee"],
 "app/assets/stylesheets"=>["application.css", "editor.css.scss"],
 "app/controllers"=>["application_controller.rb", "concerns"]}
```

Comment: Ash you are my hero! Seriously! HERO!!! This worked...I was able to isolate exactly what I needed to....I put a binding pry in my method, and tested this out in the console...with pry. Now here is my next question... has this created actual directories now, or has this just isolated the paths? If its the later...do u have any idea how I can render this are folders or nesting links in a view file?

Comment: No problem. Everything in the code above is just manipulating Strings, so this hasn't created any actual directories or touched the filesystem in any way. From "view" I assume you're using Rails? You'll want to assign it to an instance variable (@grouped = ...) in your controller and traverse it in your .erb to generate whatever markup you want; probably something like <% @grouped.each do |dir, filenames| %>. Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html for a good writeup on creating views and using erb.

Comment: Ash! Yes...I'm using rails...I've both coding for about a month and half now...totally new to code, and I'm loving it. I'm going to try it now, and I'll let u know how it goes.

Comment: Ok....so it worked! I think I still need to clean it up a bit because this is what it looks like in my view...but this is def very helpful...thanks again!

Comment: `app/models

[".keep", "gemm.rb", "reference.rb", "user.rb"]

app/models/concerns

[".keep"]

app/views/editor

["index.html.erb", "raw_code.txt"]

app/views/gemms

["_form.html.erb", "index.html.erb", "new.html.erb", "show.html.erb"]`